# Criar um executável no R através do pacote Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar um executável que vá diretamente ao painel gerado pelo código Shiny sem ter que abrir o R e executar os códigos

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Meu objetivo é que um usuário sem conhecimento em R possa utilizar esse painel, localmente em sua máquina, sem disponibilizar na web.

Comment: Fale um pouco mais sobre o ambiente em que será rodado. É Windows? O outro usuário tem acesso a um servidor ou pasta compartilhada em comum contigo?

Comment: O ambiente é o Windows, quanto ao usuário, temos a opção de pasta compatilhada, desde já agradeço

Comment: Recomendo copiar a pasta da instalação do R para a pasta que o usuário acessa. Depois fazer o batch usar o executável do R nesta pasta para rodar o shiny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os outros usuários do Windows podem executar o R por meio da instalação feita em outra máquina caso tenham acesso a pasta com os executáveis do R.

Com isso basta você criar um arquivo executável (batch) com um conteúdo similar a esse.

*app.bat*

```
caminho/do/R/na/pasta/compartilhada/Rscript.exe app.R
```

Nesse caso sua aplicação seriam os dois arquivos: `app.R` e `app.bat`. Esses dois arquivos deveriam estar na mesma pasta.

A boa prática seria instalar um shiny server e os usuários acessarem a aplicação do modo como manda a documento. Mas a forma anterior quebra um galho.

Outra alternativa é criar uma aplicação desktop usando o electron e o shiny, como proposto [nessa palestra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARrbbviGvjc).

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda